# How to send a simple data message from one user to another and bring up a page loading the data?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-in-app-messaging

I was wondering how mobile news apps send messages where if you click on the push notification, the app takes you to the specific article. I am trying to perform a similar task but have the user generate a message and send it to another user. When the user on the other end receives the message, they should be taken to another view that displays the message data.

Would I use the Firebase In-App Messaging or would I need an external server with the Firebase Admin SDK implemented?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make use of `userNotificationCenter(_:didReceive:withCompletionHandler:)`, firing the appropriate logic based on the contents of your notifications, or the action selected by the user.

See [this blog post](https://fluffy.es/open-specific-view-push-notification-tapped/) for an overview of how you can open a specific view controller from the background. As an example, this [project](https://github.com/mariohercules/ios-notification) on GitHub uses Firebase and seems to do what you're trying to do.

Comment: I was able to get this working for having the content change when a user clicks on a notification. However, how can I have the user generate the push notification and have the other user receive the notification when the app is in the background?